# How to implement search widget in fragment with Recycler View?

Tags: android, search, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a NavigationDrawer and in a fragment I implement a list with Recycler View. 
Now I want to implement a search widget in this Recycler View.

How I can do that?

this is that i have until now.

the *menu.xml*

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

the *file.java*

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();         searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }
```

Comment: do the filtering directly in your Adapter class, in order to make it async you can use custom android.widget.Filter class

Comment: @pskink can you give me an example?

Comment: How are you loading data (Cursor loader / Static data / some other way) into the Recycler View ?

Comment: I'm using CursorAdapter.